# If the radical of an ideal $I$ in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$ is generated by a single irreducible, what is $I$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $I$ be an ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$ such that its radical $\sqrt{I}$ is equal to $(g)$, where $g$ is an irreducible polynomial.

Does this imply that $I=(g^m)$ for a positive integer $m$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. For example take $n=2$. We have:

$(x^2)\subseteq (x)\cdot (x,y)\subseteq (x)$

So if we let $I=(x)\cdot (x,y)$ then $(x)=\sqrt{(x^2)}\subseteq\sqrt{I}\subseteq\sqrt{(x)}=(x)$, and so $\sqrt{I}=(x)$. However, $I$ is not generated by a power of $x$. (this is easy, I'll leave it to you to check this)